# Game since 2014 with both kings under fire

Tags: checkmate, attack

Does anyone know a game since 2014 with both players at least ELO 2000, where both
 kings are about to be checkmated and the game ends because one side cannot avoid
 checkmate ?

Comment: look up some sicilian games. Usually white castle queenside and black castles kingside and then they push their pawns up the board to mate the opponent. You'll find what you are look for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are looking for a game where both players attack the king castled on opposite sides. This is not the case in following game, but it does feature mate attacks from both sides and it is decided by one tempo. With 35....Be4 black threatens mate, but instead he gets mated himself with a nice tactic.

```
[FEN ""]
[Event "Tata Steel (Group B)"]
[Site "Wijk aan Zee NED"]
[Date "2015.01.18"]
[EventDate "2015.01.10"]
[Round "8"]
[Result "1-0"]
[White "David Navara"]
[Black "Bart Michiels"]
[ECO "C06"]
[WhiteElo "2729"]
[BlackElo "2563"]
[PlyCount "75"]

1. e4 e6 2. d4 d5 3. Nd2 Nf6 4. e5 Nfd7 5. Bd3 c5 6. c3 Nc6
7. Ne2 cxd4 8. cxd4 f6 9. exf6 Nxf6 10. O-O Bd6 11. Nf3 Qc7
12. h3 O-O 13. Be3 Bd7 14. Re1 Be8 15. Ng5 Bf7 16. Rc1 Kh8
17. a3 Bg8 18. b4 a6 19. g3 h6 20. Nf4 Bxf4 21. Bxf4 Qd7
22. Nf3 Bh7 23. b5 axb5 24. Bxb5 Qe7 25. Bxc6 bxc6 26. Rxc6
Ne4 27. Re3 Ra7 28. Rb3 Qf6 29. Qc1 Qf5 30. Rc8 Ra8 31. Rc7
Qxh3 32. Rbb7 Ng5 33. Nxg5 hxg5 34. Rxg7 gxf4 35. Qc7 Be4
36. Rg8+ Rxg8 37. Qe5+ Rg7 38. Qxg7+ 1-0
```